# Is $\pmb{\eta}\cdot\pmb{\omega_1} = (\pmb{\eta} + \pmb{1})\cdot\pmb{\omega_1}$?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

- $\pmb{\eta}$ - [order type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_type) of [$\mathbb{Q}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_numbers).
- $\pmb{1}$ - order type of a singleton set.
- $\pmb{\omega_0}$ - order type of [$\mathbb{N}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_numbers).
- $\pmb{\omega_1}$ - order type of [the first uncountable ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal).

It is easy to see that $\pmb{\eta}\cdot\pmb{\omega_0} = (\pmb{\eta} + \pmb{1})\cdot\pmb{\omega_0}$, in fact, both sides are $\pmb{\eta}$.

*Question*:
Is $\pmb{\eta}\cdot\pmb{\omega_1} = (\pmb{\eta} + \pmb{1})\cdot\pmb{\omega_1}$?

Comment: You define the product as the order type of the lexicographic ordering, right? Namely, $\eta\cdot\omega_1$ is the order type of replacing every rational by a copy of $\omega_1$.

Comment: @AsafKaragila I was assuming it was the "reverse" lexicographic ordering like the one used for ordinal multiplication.

Comment: Oh, makes sense. So $\eta\cdot\omega_1$ is stacking up $\omega_1$ many copies of $\mathbb Q$?

Comment: @AsafKaragila He claims that $\eta \cdot \omega_0 = \eta$. If you replace every rational by a copy of $\omega_0$, then you are no longer dense. It can not be isomorphic to $\eta$.

Comment: The product is defined so that $\pmb{\eta}\cdot\pmb{\omega_1}$ is dense.

Comment: I have an idea, but I can't put it into formality due to a notational nightmare.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a proposed solution, I have not verified all the details, but I believe this should work.

Let $\mathbb Q^\ast$ be the rational numbers plus an endpoint, let $A,B$ be a partition of this set to intervals such that $A$ has order type $\eta$. In $\mathbb Q$ fix some partition into two parts $X,Y$ such that both are intervals and $X$ is of order type $\eta+1$.

For $\alpha<\omega_1$ we write $A_\alpha,B_\alpha,X_\alpha,Y_\alpha$ to be the corresponding parts in the $\alpha$-th copies of $\mathbb Q,\mathbb Q^\ast$.

Now we define by induction:

- For $\alpha=0$ simply send $A_0+B_0$ into $X_0$, and $A_1$ into $Y_0$.
- If $\alpha$ is a limit ordinal, do the same. Namely $A_\alpha+B_\alpha$ into $X_\alpha$ and $A_{\alpha+1}$ into $Y_\alpha$.
- If $\alpha=\beta+1$, send $B_\alpha$ into $X_\alpha$ and $A_{\alpha+1}$ into $Y_\alpha$.

It is clear that arriving at any limit ordinal $\alpha$ we have an isomorphism of $(\eta+1)\cdot\alpha$ into $\eta\cdot\alpha$, so the step taken at the limit ordinal itself is well-defined (we do not need to worry about embedding $A_\alpha$ in a prior step).

It is clearly an order isomorphism, and it is a bijection for obvious reasons too.

Comment: I think the key point is that $(\eta + 1)\cdot \omega_1$ is just $\omega_1$ copies of $(\eta + 1)\cdot \omega$ one after another, because $\omega_1$ is $\omega_1$ copies of $\omega$. We already have an isomorphism for $(\eta + 1)\cdot \omega$.

Comment: @Carl: Yes, that is exactly what I had in mind!

Comment: @CarlMummert That is a great explanation!