# Is $(\pmb{1} + \pmb{\eta})\cdot\pmb{\omega_1} = \pmb{1} + \pmb{\eta}\cdot\pmb{\omega_1}$?

Tags: set-theory, order-theory, ordinals

- $\pmb{\eta}$ - [order type](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_type) of [$\mathbb{Q}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rational_numbers).
- $\pmb{1}$ - order type of a singleton set.
- $\pmb{\omega_0}$ - order type of [$\mathbb{N}$](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Natural_numbers).
- $\pmb{\omega_1}$ - order type of [the first uncountable ordinal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/First_uncountable_ordinal).

It is easy to see that $\pmb{\eta}\cdot\pmb{\omega_0} = (\pmb{\eta} + \pmb{1})\cdot\pmb{\omega_0} = \pmb{\eta}$ and $(\pmb{1} + \pmb{\eta})\cdot\pmb{\omega_0} = \pmb{1} + \pmb{\eta}\cdot\pmb{\omega_0} = \pmb{1} + \pmb{\eta}$.
As it was shown in the answer to my [last question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/173998/is-pmb-eta-cdot-pmb-omega-1-pmb-eta-pmb1-cdot-pmb-omega-1), we also have $(\pmb{\eta} + \pmb{1})\cdot\pmb{\omega_1} =  (\pmb{\eta}+\pmb{1})\cdot\pmb{\omega_0}\cdot\pmb{\omega_1}= \pmb{\eta}\cdot\pmb{\omega_1} $.

*Question*:
Is $(\pmb{1} + \pmb{\eta})\cdot\pmb{\omega_1} = \pmb{1} + \pmb{\eta}\cdot\pmb{\omega_1}$?

Comment: This is a bit more challenging than the other one :-)

Comment: Since this is the second question of a series, I'd like to ask whether there is some motivation behind them?

Comment: I try to get a better understanding of the order type $\pmb{\eta}\cdot\pmb{\omega_1}$. It looks really weird for my poor intuition: it is uncountable, but every proper initial segment is $\pmb{\eta}$ or $\pmb{\eta}+\pmb{1}$. I wonder if there is only one such example or there are more?

Comment: That makes sense - I wasn't sure where these were coming from.

Comment: @Vladimir: Then you might also be interested in [this answer](http://math.stackexchange.com/a/173412), which also relies on this strange elusiveness of the uncountability. I found the analogy helpful that every initial segment of $\mathbb N$ is finite and yet $\mathbb N$ is infinite.

Comment: @joriki: after thinking a little more, I share your concern about the $\omega_1$ stage of the idea I had put in an answer, and I am going to delete that answer. Thanks for your helpful comments.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Here is a somewhat relaxed way to see that the orders $1+\eta\cdot\omega_1$ and $(1+\eta)\cdot\omega_1$ are not isomorphic, by finding a topological feature of one order not exhibited in the other.

First, observe that $(1+\eta)\cdot\omega_1$ has a closed subset of
order type $\omega_1$, namely, the points corresponding to the
initial point of each of the intervals $1+\eta$ used to create it. This suborder contains limit points for all its increasing $\omega$-sequences.

But meanwhile, $1+\eta\cdot\omega_1$ has no such suborder. This is because this order contains no limits of sequences of points from distinct intervals (the $\eta$ intervals used to build it), but any subset
of order type $\omega_1$ will have increasing sequences of points from distinct intervals.

So they are not isomorphic.

Answer (score 12):

$(1+\eta)\cdot\omega_1\ne 1+\eta\cdot\omega_1$. Equivalently, I’ll show that $\eta+(1+\eta)\cdot\omega_1\ne\eta\cdot\omega_1$.

Let $Q_0=\omega_1\times\big(\Bbb Q\cap[0,1)\big)$ and $Q=\omega_1\times\Bbb Q$, ordered lexicographically. Let $X=Q_0\setminus\{\langle 0,0\rangle\}$, and suppose that $h:X\to Q$ is an order-isomorphism. For each limit ordinal $\xi\in\omega_1$ let $\langle\xi_k:k\in\omega\rangle$ be a strictly increasing sequence of ordinals with limit $\xi$. Then

$$\Big\langle h\big(\langle\xi_k,0\rangle\big):k\in\omega\Big\rangle\nearrow h\big(\langle\xi,0\rangle\big)\;.$$

If $h\big(\langle\xi,0\rangle\big)=\langle f(\xi),q_\xi\rangle$, there is an $n(\xi)\in\omega$ such that $h\big(\langle\xi_k,0\rangle\big)\in\{f(\xi)\}\times(\leftarrow,q_\xi)_{\Bbb Q}$ for $k\ge n(\xi)$. The map $\xi\mapsto\xi_{n(\xi)}$ is a pressing-down function on the cub of limit ordinals in $\omega_1$, so there is a stationary subset $S$ of limit ordinals and an $\alpha\in\omega_1$ such that $\xi_{n(\xi)}=\alpha$ for each $\xi\in S$. Then for each $\xi\in S$ we have $h\big(\langle\alpha,0\rangle\big)\in\{f(\xi)\}\times(\leftarrow,q_\xi)_{\Bbb Q}$, so there is some $\beta\in\omega_1$ such that $f(\xi)=\beta$ for each $\xi\in S$. But then $h\big[S\times\{0\}\big]\subseteq\{\beta\}\times\Bbb Q$, which is absurd, since $|S\times\{0\}|=\omega_1$, $\{\beta\}\times\Bbb Q$ is countable, and $h$ is injective.

Comment: This answer is one more reason to upvote the question :-) (and the answer).

Comment: Is it possible to somehow visualize what is different between these orders? They both look for me exactly like $\eta$, but "longer". And, indeed, all proper initial segments are $\eta$ or $\eta+1$.

Comment: @Vladimir: In the other case, the $1$s are always adjacent to the $\eta$ of the successor ordinal, so they're sandwiched between two $\eta$s and are relatively easy to deal with. In the present case, because they're at the front, we'd need predecessor ordinals to deal with them in a regular fashion, but limit ordinals don't have predecessors, and Brian's proof shows that it's impossible to choose *ersatz* predecessors in a consistent manner.